# steering 3 LEDs with double button

Tags: led, switches

I want to control 3 LEDs with 2 switches. First switch turns first LED on, second switch second LED, and if both switches are on, all three LEDs are ON.
Switches are sharing common input.

This is trivial schematic for first two LEDs, how to connect third one to achieve this goal? Do I need to use transistors for this?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpkfUk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: wow, this was confusing at first: Please, always, make your ground be at the bottom of your schematics.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know it should be like this, my knowledge of schematics is rather poor unfortunately. Thanks.

Comment: Do the first two have to stay on or go off?

Comment: The easy way is make a truth table.2 inputs, 4 possible combinations, 4 used states

Comment: First two LEDs should stay on.

Comment: Please put the additional details in the question rather than buried in the comments. Do the two switches share a common pin that would make Christobol's solution unworkable? If so add that detail into your question as well. (Do you see how difficult it is to answer when all the details aren't supplied?)

Comment: Well, this is my first question here, so I'm learning even how to ask them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do what you are asking for:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdxwCu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It worked, thanks!

Comment: alternatively you can connect the bottom of D1 to the base of Q1 and not need R4.

Comment: That will reduce the brightness of D1 so the value of R1 should be less to compensate for the 0.7V drop.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEo88Y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer, unfortunately I can't use it with my case, because I have double switch with common input pin.

Comment: Still the most clever passive solution

Answer (score 1):

Use an AND gate!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzcmmr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany's answer will work too. I think it's beneficial to show both

Comment: I used @Spehro Pefhany's solution but for learning purposes your answer is definitely beneficial, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the threshold voltage of the LED can be exploited to cause the middle led to require both supplies to be on.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWH60m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>